# Lit-Element - Types have separate declarations of a private property

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

Trying to compile a typescript project that uses lit-element and lit-html and has dependencies to other projects that use lit-html too gives me the error

```
.../lit-html/lib/parts").NodePart' is not assignable to type 'import(".../lit-html/lib/parts").NodePart'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property '__pendingValue'.
```

I'm using webpack@4.42.1 to try to compile the project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tsconfig to force it to use a single source for lit-html:

```
    "paths": {
      ...
      "lit-html": ["node_modules/lit-html"],
      "lit-html*": ["node_modules/lit-html/*"],
   
    }
```